# ASP.NET MVC project with a section written in Angular2: a build error occurs when using MvcBuildViews

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angular, visual-studio-2015

Ok it could be a singular combination...

### INTRODUCTION

I have an **existing ASP.NET MVC 5 project**.
It contains a **private "Admin" area**. I'm planning to change this area **migrating it to Angular2** (+ WebAPI) :)

Due to some business requirements, I can't change the architecture of the original "Main" website (separating the Admin section into another website) so I must host inside it the new "Admin" area written in Angular2.

Main website url: `http://www.example.com`
Admin area url: `http://www.example.com/admin`

This is also true for the **Visual Studio Project**:
**I created a folder "admin" and put all Angular2 stuff in it**.

All works fine...

### THE ISSUE

My ASP.NET project uses the **MvcBuildViews** parameter to build the MVC views **on Release mode**.

Now when I run the build in Release mode I receive this error:

> \node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\test\data\web.config(29): error
>   ASPCONFIG: It is an error to use a section registered as
>   allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.  This
>   error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an
>   application in IIS.

The error doesn't have sense for me...

MSBUILD has analyzed a web.config file inside the "node_modules". 
The `node_modules` folder has been created in the project root folder after "npm install" (necessary to prepare angular2's stuff).

These folder should be ignored by msbuild... IMHO

HEY... node_modules IT IS NOT included in the VS project. MSBUILD is scanning the folder because it is only present inside the project...

### WORKAROUNDS

1. **Give up the MvcBuildViews**... but I think this setting is very useful to detect errors during development phase
2. **Hide the node_modules folder**. This is the current workaround I'm using. I've added this pre-build event `attrib +h "$(ProjectDir)node_modules"`

Some other solution?
I've googled with no success...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue recently. I found the solution to this issue in the following article:

[Excluding node_modules folder from ASP.NET compilation](https://matthewrwilton.wordpress.com/2017/03/12/excluding-node_modules-folder-from-asp-net-compilation/)

The article suggest to replace the `AspNetCompiler` task in your csproj for a direct call to `aspnet_compiler.exe` which support excluding folders. In the article, it does so by hardcoding the path to that .exe file. Which for most of the cases is Ok.

You may also use `$(FrameworkDir)` and `$(FrameworkVersion)` to avoid hardcoding the path or if you are unsure where the `aspnet_compiler.exe` may be:

```
<Target Name="MvcBuildViews" AfterTargets="AfterBuild" Condition="'$(MvcBuildViews)'=='true'">
    <Exec Command="$(FrameworkDir)\$(FrameworkVersion)\aspnet_compiler.exe -v temp -p $(WebProjectOutputDir) -x node_modules"/>
</Target>
```